# Firebase updating nested data without deleting

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, calling `updateChildren` on my database is erasing all data currently located there. The JSON tree looks like this

```
{
  "user1" : {
    "messages" : {
      "-message1" : true
    },
    "userId" : "value"
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to insert message 2 under message 1, however, all it does is replaces *message 1* with *message 2*

```
fun addToCurrentUser() {
    val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
    val id = user?.uid
    val map: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    map.put(message.getId(), true)
    root.child("users/" + id + "/messages/").updateChildren(map)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new data at a known location, you can just use [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) on the path directly, disregarding anything else in the path.

```
root
    .child("users")
    .child(id)
    .child("messages")
    .child(message.getId())
    .seValue(true)
```

If you target any node for an update, everything under that location will be replace, so it's better to target as deep as possible to make the required change.